# Get only certain property from generic list of custom class using lambda expressions

Tags: lambda, generic-list

Assume

```
class Person
{
string FirstName;
string LastName;
int Age;
}
```

and a list

```
List<Person> listPerson;
```

Possible ways to get a list of only first names of all the person in this list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your easiest way will be

`List<string> firstNames = listPerson.Select(p => p.FirstName).ToList()`

But in order to do this, you'll need to make the properties public.